# ErrorException running php artisan vendor:publish with Elqouent-Sluggable

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and attempting to install [Eloquent-Sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable). I have followed all the steps in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#installation-and-requirements):

1. `composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable`
2. `composer update`
3. Add `Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider::class` to the Providers in `config/app.php`
4. `php artisan vendor:publish`

The last step resulted in this error message:

> [ErrorException] Argument 2 passed to
>   Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTableCommand::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Composer, instance of
>   Illuminate\Support\Composer given, called in
>   C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\cvi
>   ebrock\eloquent-sluggable\src\SluggableServiceProvider.php on line 92 and defined

What caused the error to occur?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. This is because the `SluggableTableCommand` requires `Composer` instance in its constructor but accidentally different type of instance is passed.

This might not be the smartest way to fix this but if you are in rush you can just remove the Composer declaration before `$composer` in the `SluggableTableCommand` constructor. The file that you need to edit is `vendor/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/src/SluggableTableCommand.php` on line 44

This should work:

```
 /**
 * Create a new migration sluggable instance.
 *
 * @param SluggableMigrationCreator $creator
 * @param Composer $composer
 */
public function __construct(
  SluggableMigrationCreator $creator,
  $composer
) {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->creator = $creator;
    $this->composer = $composer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using Laravel 5.2.29 when I tried to create migration via console command

```
php artisan sluggable:table posts slug
```

What solved the issue was creation usual Laravel migration, but I had commented 'Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider::class' row in config/app.php file before.

```
php artisan make:migration add_slug_to_posts_table
```

with the next code in migration file

```
public function up(){
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();
    });
}

public function down(){
    Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropColumn('slug');
    });
}
```

and ran the migration

```
 php artisan migrate
```